# Keep one variable the same within the class (with multiple functions) for reuse elsewhere

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have a class script (`secondary.py`), that when called in my `main.py` file, works. My issue is that I want to call the second function below in another script, `tertiary.py`, and that the output variable `reg_name` be the same for both of the functions below -

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Class to keep randomly pulled name the same throughout ----
class NameHandle():

    # init 
    def __init__(self):
       
        # reads in csv with a celeb's name in one col & their twitter handle in the second col - e.g. name: Oprah  &   handle: @oprah
        # kicker: since the row is randomly chosen, it *needs* to stay the same throughout

        handle_csv = pd.read_csv('handle_list.csv')
        ran_line = handle_csv.sample(n = 1, replace = False)
        self.reg_name = ran_line['name'].to_string()
        print("test one" + self.reg_name)    ### test print 
        self.handle_tag = ran_line['handle'].to_string()

    # format randomly pulled celeb name and twitter handle
    def name_and_handle(self):

        # create & format sentence, to send back to main.py
        print("test two" + self.reg_name)    ### test print
        sentence = self.reg_name + "'s Twitter handle is" + ' ' + self.handle_tag
        sentence = re.sub(r'\d+', '', sentence)
        sentence = " ".join(re.split("\s+", sentence, flags = re.UNICODE))
        return sentence

    # function to keep celeb name the same through the entire process
    def name_insurance(self):

        same_name = self.reg_name
        print("test three" + same_name)    ### test print
        return same_name

# Main function ----
if __name__ == '__main__':
    NameHandle().name_and_handle()
    NameHandle().name_insurance()
```

If I call the function `name_and_handle()` in the `main.py` script - it works. If I call the second function, `name_insurance()`, in the main or any other script, I get a different name, *not* the same name. The three `print()` statements confirm that. I'm missing something easy - very new to classes - if this is a **stupid** question, crucify me below, and I'll delete.

```
# Calling `secondary.py` in `main.py`

import secondary as sd

# outputs different names
sd.NameHandle().name_and_handle()
sd.NameHandle().name_insurance()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you've got `ran_line = handle_csv.sample(n = 1, replace = False)` meaning you'll get a random line every time you create a new instance of your class `NameHandler`.

Every time you `NameHandle()` you're creating a new instance, so, getting a new random line.

Just create the class instance once and use that instance to call the functions on.

```
name_handle_instance = sd.NameHandle()
name_handle_instance.name_and_handle()
name_handle_instance.name_insurance()
```

I don't know why it would work under `__main__` but not when imported.

Comment: Would it be better if the `handle_csv` and `ran_line` lines were above the `init`, but under the class name (I did try, but the `self.`'s did not work)? Also this isn't an idiotic question?

Comment: @papelr I'm not quite sure I understand. Are you talking about in the 3 line example I put in? because that wouldn't work, because you don't yet have the instance of `NameHandle` created to access. Maybe check out this page about different types of functions - https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/

Comment: thanks @martineau - updated my terminology